# ggplot doesn't display the colors in the bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

My bar graph below doesn't show the colors in the bars.

```
ggplot(top5_energyProducersMod, aes(year, ggwt_hours), fill = year) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~country_name)
```

[image]

I'm using the R studio desktop version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fill color goes with the aesthetics:

```
ggplot(top5_energyProducersMod, aes(year, ggwt_hours,fill = year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~country_name)
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot